# Storing react form data to google sheet

Tags: reactjs, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to store my form data to google sheet, but every time when I click the button it's an update only one row, I want when I click every time it's should be store in a new row. 
Also, I want to save in a row not column but right now it's store value in a col.
I have connected google API and authentication. If there's an easy way to add data in Google sheet kindly let me know. I didn't find any solution right now.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const Test = () => {
const SHEET_ID = '1iQeoKog_yKXAh4vcmdxqnnS-DLbC3Pgdn5FaT_4lM-E';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ya29.a0Adw1xeV7QH5E12O-pNxPkSfWK4_J-y5QtVxldMD7kjmEL5-hlTsnI792Zaa5uVapN5hlebN4B8S1xSfsWu82VYrh3NOnXCK4a9Lxvr-PfRx_aCsAXzBmb2Z-MrJnWyUPIo01yUavSrpiD9u4LkXiioG1QWKj9FesIhU';

   const updateSheetValues = () => {
    fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SHEET_ID}:batchUpdate`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        //update this token with yours. 
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({

        "requests": [
          {
            "updateCells": {
              "range": {
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endColumnIndex": 1,
                "endRowIndex": 3,
                "sheetId": 0
              },
              " ": [
                {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "userEnteredValue": {
                        "stringValue": "Adnan1"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "userEnteredValue": {
                        "stringValue": "Adnan2"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "userEnteredValue": {
                        "stringValue": "Adnan3"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "fields": "*"
            }
          }
        ]

      })
    })
  }

    return ( 
      <div className = "App" >
        hello world 
        <button onClick={updateSheetValues}>Update A1</button>
      </div>
    );

}

export default Test;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to append a row instead of updating the existent one, you need to use the method [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Thereby, to pass the values as a row instead of a column the format should be:

```
"values": [
        [
          "Adnan1",
          "Adnan2",
          "Adnan3"
        ]
```

Url:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SHEET_ID}/values/{RANGE}:append
```

Sample request:

```
{
  "range": "A15",
  "values": [
    [
      "Adnan1",
      "Adnan2",
      "Adnan3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Thereby, `range` designates the first cell from where the first empty row will be searched downwards (in the sample range is set to `A15`, but in your case you probably want to set range to `A1`. Mind that the {range} in the url needs to be the same like within the request

Comment: show error : 400 https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${SHEET_ID}/values/A2:append

Comment: Did you paste your sheet id instead of ${SHEET_ID}? did you set all the required parameters? I recommend you to make a test request with the "Try this API" before incroporaitng it into Javascript

Comment: in test api everything working fine, but once i do with react it's show me error

Comment: What is your full code you try to implement in React?

Comment: I can't see nothing wrong with your code, but a 400 error usually originates from invalid credentials (especially if the error only occurs when authenticating with the access token in react, not with "Try this API"). Are you sure that your access token is still valid? Be aware that it expires after 1 hour and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: I think that your request body is required to be modified. So how about modifying to `body: JSON.stringify({majorDimension: "ROWS", values: [["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"], ["Engine", "$100", "1", "3/20/2016"]]})` and testing it again? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) But in this case, it supposes that `SHEET_ID` and `ACCESS_TOKEN` are the valid values. And also, when I saw the script, it seems that the response values from Sheets API is not checked. I think that by this, the error message cannot be confirmed.